# Jquery/PHP - Prevent user from browsing to locked content

Tags: php, jquery, authentication

I have this simple login script:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'authorize.php',
        data: { username: user, password: pass },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.status == "loggedIn") {
                //Logged in
            } else {
                //Not logged in
            }
        }
    });
```

Where `//Logged in` is, how should I call the page that required the login? I could simply `$.load` the page, but then what was the point of verifying a login when the user could just browse to this file in the first place?

Comment: I hope you check in the included file, if the user is logged in. If not, your whole login is useless.

Comment: I'd suggest using [`PHP Sessions`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) across all of these pages.  Make a check on the page you're going to `$.load` that the user is actually logged in and set the user as logged in on the `authorize.php` page if successful.

Comment: That won't prevent a user from navigating to the resource manually, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using [`PHP Sessions`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) across all of these pages. Make a check on the page you're going to `$.load` that the user is actually logged in and set the user as logged in on the `authorize.php` page if successful.

This way, if a user looks at the page source and see's what you're loading, but when they try and access that page it won't do anything because you're checking to see if they've been logged in already.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of presentation, you can just load a div on another file, you don't need to load the whole thing.

I use ajax to login and $.load to "bring" a div I have in a template file. It's just because it makes it easier when you need to change the design.

Remember that splitting the work into individual "pieces" makes it easier for you to change things. Imagine you have the same login box on 20 individual templates. If you change one, you have to change 19 more.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent a user from doing anything with javascript (jquery), since it is client-side and easily disabled/changed etc.

What you can do is simply `$.load` the page like you say, but also have a check against the session on the loaded page that checks for an actual login before sending the content.  You'd need to set some variable in the session as part of authorize.php to indicate a successful login.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent data from being accessed, you should look into using `.htaccess` and Apache's [`mod_rewrite`](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite). Whenever a user requests a piece of possibly sensitive data, you'll invisibly call a PHP page which will then serve up either the requested data or a `403 Forbidden`.

Example:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user-content/(.+) display_content.php?file=$1
```

Then, any files that would be accessed in user-content will be rerouted through `display_content.php`. You can also use this `.htaccess` file to help prevent hotlinking by refusing to display the resource if there's a referrer.

**display_content.php**

```
<?php
if (isLoggedIn($_COOKIE["username"], $_COOKIE["password"]) && isset($_GET["file"])) {
    if (mimeTypeOk($_GET["file"]) { // Implementation not shown
        readfile($_GET["file"]);
        exit();
    }
}
header("403 Forbidden");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this the most secure way, you are going to have to use both jQuery as a client-side way and PHP as a server-side way of checking if the user is logged in.  You don't need to load the entire page with jQuery, just use the following code to load only a div portion:

```
$("#load_dom").click(function(){  
$("#result")  
    .html(ajax_load)  
    .load(loadUrl + " #picture");  
});
```

Then, as a security measure, use PHP to restrict access to the page, by checking $_SESSION vars like this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    // user is logged in
} else {
    // user is not logged in
    die("You are not logged in.");
}
```